# strtotime PHP, display date/time

Tags: php, xml, datetime, strtotime

I have an XML file with a "Time" attribute. I am calling this XML into my PHP and giving it the variable $game_time.

An example value for the attribute is "10:30 PM"...

Since it is coming from XML, it is reading "10:30 PM" as a string.

Now my question, how can I convert this string to an actual timestamp?

I think I need to use strtotime somehow, but can't get the syntax right...

I am wanting this XML time to be converted to a timestamp because I am eventually going to compare this time with the server's time and shoot out a conditional output...

Thanks, John

Comment: No love from anyone? No clue? No help?

Comment: You will need to be a bit more patient, not every question on here is answered within a minute.

Comment: you mean `strtotime($game_time)` is not giving you the correct output?

Comment: When $game_time is set to "8:30 PM"

strtotime($game_time) is outputting 1314232200...

Now how do I convert that output to a timestamp that looks like "10:30" again... Basically, I am trying to convert a string (which is actually a time), to a data type (time) that would allow me to compare it with the server's time.

Answer (score 7):

you can use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$xmldata = '10:30 PM';
echo strtotime($xmldata);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($xmldata));
```

that will output:

```
1314250200

2011-08-24 22:30:00
```

If you don't specify a DATE, the current day will be use.

Comment: Now how do I convert that output to a timestamp that looks like "10:30" again... Basically, I am trying to convert a string (which is actually a time), to a data type (time) that would allow me to compare it with the server's time.

Comment: as a reminder, if you use php 5.1.0 or before, strtotime will return -1 otherwise it returns FALSE. so you can always add validation in your script to make sure you have a valid time.

Answer (score 4):

you can use **strtotime**

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time_stamp = strtotime("10:00 AM"); //1314180000
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $time_stamp); //August 24, 2011, 10:00 am
?>
```